# setImageRessource(R.drawable.image) in fragment crashes

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to change an image of an ImageView from a fragment by using setImageResource(R.drawable.etape_todo); but the application crashes without any logs.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot
Max

```
public class PlateauJeu extends Fragment {
    public static  ImageView EtatEtape1;  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plateau_layout, container, false);
        ImageView etatEtape1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEtape1); 
   
        PlateauJeu.EtatEtape1.setImageResource(R.drawable.etape_passed);

        return view;
    }

    public static void nouvelleEtape(Context context){
        EtatEtape1.setImageResource(R.drawable.etape_todo);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plateau_layout, container, false);
ImageView etatEtape1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEtape1); 
   
PlateauJeu.EtatEtape1.setImageResource(R.drawable.etape_passed);
```

Be careful ! You're setting an Image in a not initialized component. I think you wanted to do this :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plateau_layout, container, false);
EtatEtape1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEtape1); 
EtatEtape1.setImageResource(R.drawable.etape_passed);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bruno !!!